# page.injectJs not working with node-phantom

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs

Why does the following code return the error:

```
phantom stdout: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
```

I am injecting jQuery into the page and trying to find a selector:

**UPDATED CODE BELOW** (See comments)

```
portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(startPort, 60000, 'localhost', function(err, freeport) {
    if(err) {
        //console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(freeport);
    phantom.create({'port': freeport}, function(ph){

        return ph.createPage(function(page) {
            return page.open("http://www.targetsite.com/showpost.php?p="+posts[index].post_id, function(status) {
                console.log("opened post? ", status);

                var post_id = posts[index].post_id;
                page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js',function(err, post_id){
                    console.log(err);
                    return page.evaluate(function(post_id){
                        return $('#post_message_'+post_id); //undefined
                    },function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                        return ph.exit();
                    });

                });


            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: @dcodesmith yep, same error.

Comment: Check if an error is caught on injection. `page.injectJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js',function(err){console.log(err)}`

Comment: @dcodesmith tried that (see above). No error is caught.

Comment: Ok, next step, could u confirm that the page actually opens, check the `status`. @codecowboy

Comment: @dcodesmith looks like the problem was that I needed includeJs not injectJs. The page is definitely loading. The one remaining problem I have is passing post_id. It is undefined where I need it. I have updated the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42497/discussion-between-codecowboy-and-dcodesmith)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
return page.evaluate(function(post_id){
    return $('#post_message_'+post_id); //undefined
},function(result){
    console.log(result);
    return ph.exit();
}, post_id);
```

BTW which node module are using for this?

[**phantomjs-node evaluate wiki**](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node/wiki#evaluating-pages)

Comment: Also results in undefined and an additional error: phantom stdout: TypeError: '19350369' is not a function (evaluating 'cb(page.evaluate.apply(page, [fn].concat(args)))')

Comment: Thanks - this worked! Looks like I didn't RTFM https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node/wiki#evaluating-pages. Sandboxing was very relevant in this case as I needed to past post_id from my node.js script to the page